# find keystrokes for On Screen Keyboard scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, mergesort, fold, foldleft

I am trying to solve a recent interview question using Scala..

You have an on screen keyboard which is a grid of 6 rows , 5 columns each. With alphabets from A to Z and blank space are arranged in the grid row first.

You can use this on screen keyboard to type words.. by using your TV Remote by press Left, Right, Up , Down or OK keys to type each character.

Question: given an input string, find the sequence of keystrokes needed to be pressed on the remote to type the input.

The code implementation can be found at

https://github.com/mradityagoyal/scala/blob/master/OnScrKb/src/main/scala/OnScrKB.scala

I have tried to solve this using three different approaches..

1. Simple forldLeft.

   ```
   def keystrokesByFL(input: String, startChar: Char = 'A'): String = {
   val zero = ("", startChar)
   //(acc, last) + next => (acc+ aToB , next) 
   def op(zero: (String, Char), next: Char): (String, Char) = zero match {
     case (acc, last) => (acc + path(last, next), next)
   }
   val result = input.foldLeft(zero)(op)
   result._1
   ```

   }
2. divide and conquer - Uses divide and conquer mechanism. The algorithm is similar to merge sort. * We split the input word into two if the length is > 3 * we recursively call the subroutine to get the path of left and right halves from the split. * In the end.. we add the keystrokes for first + keystrokes from end of first string to start of second string + keystrokes for second. * Essentially we divide the input string in two smaller halves till we get to size 4. for smaller than 4 we use the fold right.

   ```
   def keystrokesByDnQ(input: String, startChar: Char = 'A'): String = {
   def splitAndMerge(in: String, startChar: Char): String = {
     if (in.length() < 4) {
       //if length is <4 then dont split.. as you might end up with one side having only 1 char. 
       keystrokesByFL(in, startChar)
     } else {
       //split
       val (x, y) = in.splitAt(in.length() / 2)
       splitAndMerge(x, startChar) + splitAndMerge(y, x.last)
     }
   }
   splitAndMerge(input, startChar)
   ```

   }
3. Fold - uses the property that the underlying operation is associative (but not commutative). * For eg.. the keystrokes("ABCDEFGHI", startChar = 'A') == keystrokes("ABC", startChar='A')+keystrokes("DEF", 'C') + keystrokes("GHI", 'F')

   ```
   def keystrokesByF(input: String, startChar: Char = 'A'): String = {
     val mapped = input.map { x => PathAcc(text = "" + x, path = "") } // map each character in input to case class PathAcc("CharAsString", "")
     val z = PathAcc(text = ""+startChar, path = "") //the starting char. 

     def op(left: PathAcc, right: PathAcc): PathAcc = {
     PathAcc(text = left.text + right.text, path = left.path + path(left.text.last, right.text.head) + right.path)
     }
     val foldresult = mapped.fold(z)(op)

     foldresult.path
   }
   ```

My questions:
1. Is the divide and conquer approach better than Fold?

2. are Fold and Divide and conquer better than foldLeft (for this specific problem)
3. Is there a way i can represent the divide and conquer approach or the Fold approach as a Monad? I can see the associative law being satisfied... but i am not able to figure out if a monoid is present here.. and if yes.. what does it achieve for me?
4. Is Divide and conquer approach the best one available for this particular problem?
5. Which approach is better suited for spark?

Any suggestions are welcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
def keystrokes(input: String, start: Char): String =
 ((start + input) zip input).par.map((path _).tupled).fold("")(_ ++ _)
```

The main point here is using the `par` method to parallelize the sequence of `(Char, Char)`, so that it can parallelize the `map`, and take the optimal implementation for `fold`.

The algorithm simply take the characters in the `String` two by two (representing the units of path to be walked), computes the path between them, and then concatenates the result. Note that `fold("")(_ ++ _)` is basically `mkString` (although `mkString` on parallel collection is implemented by `seq.mkString` so it is much less efficient).

What your implementations dearly miss is parallelization of tasks. Even in your divide-and-conquer approach, you never run code in parallel, so you will wait for the first half to be finished before starting the second half (even though they are totally independant).

Assuming you use parallelization, the classical implementation of `fold` on parallel sequences is precisely the divide-and-conquer algorithm you described, but it may be that it is better optimized (for instance, it may choose another value than `3` for chunk size, I tend to trust the scala-collection implementers on these matters).

Note that `fold` on `String` is probably implemented with `foldLeft`, so there is no added value than what you did with `foldLeft`, unless you use `.par` before.

Back to your questions (I'll mostly repeat what I just said):

1) Yes, the divide and conquer is better than fold... on `String` (but not on parallelized `String`)

2) Fold can only be better than FoldLeft with some kind of parallelization, in which case it will be as good as (or better than, if there is a better implementation for a particular parallelized collection) divide-and-conquer.

3) I don't see what monads have to do with anything here. the operator and zero for `fold` must indeed form a monoid (otherwise, you'll have some problems with operation ordering if the operator is not associative, and unwanted noise if zero is not a neutral element).

4) Yes, that I know of, once parallelized

5) Spark is inherently parallel, so the main issue would be to join all the pieces back together in the end. What I mean is that an `RDD` is not ordered, so you'll need to keep some information on which piece of input should be put where in your cluster. Once you've done that correctly (using partitions and such, this would probably be a whole question itself), using `map` and `fold` still works as a charm (Spark was designed to have an API as close as possible to scala-collection, so that's really nice here).